# Reset move gizmo to object face or geometry

Tags: transform-orientation, gizmo

After rotation has been applied to an object, is there an easy way to re-align the move gizmo back to the object geometry?

NOTE : All gizmos in the image are LOCAL, not global. A shows the desired result, B is what I have now.

[image]

Comment: it's answered here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192615/setting-an-objects-origin-to-match-its-face-normals

Answer (score 1):

Its quite easy if you are using the latest blender versions. After you have rotated your object and applied the rotation, simply go to "Options" and select Affect only - origin.
[image: Affect only Origin]

Now you can simply rotate your Origin using either the Rotation tool or Rotation Shortcut "R". [image]

After you are done rotating the origin you can exit the Affect only - Origin mode.

Note : You can not only rotate the origin, but also can Move the origin and also use Snap features.

Comment: yes but if you want to correctly align with the face, don't you need to first create a custom orientation, then Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation, then Operator box > Orientation > Face?

Comment: @moonboots. That worked great - as per your link in the comment above. Many thanks.