# Snap rotation doesn't work

Tags: snapping

I am trying to rotate the object precisely on the z axis.
I have activated the increment rotation snapping but it looks like it snaps it to the wrong axis:

[image]

The object was made by spinning a Bézier curve.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the object's local orientation aligned with the global orientation?

Comment: no, that's not what I meant, please press Alt R then see if the object is aligned with the global axis

Comment: @moonboots what do you mean aligned?

Comment: what happens if you select your object in Object mode and press Alt R, are the faces of your object aligned with the X, Y and Z axis of the world? If they are not, snapping won't align your object, you need to realign it with the global axis

Comment: @moonboots it looks like this: https://ibb.co/mHVrx9b

Comment: yes so it doesn't seem to be aligned, you need to realign the object with the global axis, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192615/setting-an-objects-origin-to-match-its-face-normals

Comment: @moonboots thank you.