# sculpting mirror is not topological

Tags: animation, sculpting

Is there possibility to mirror based on topology? Now After Moving the mesh with Armature, sculpting mirror option works in local coordinates without taking the account modified mesh. May be there an addon that can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mirroring is based on the origin of the object and you can transform the the origin this way adjusting how the mirroring works:

[image]

With Affect Only Origins enabled all transform operators( <kbd>G</kbd> ,  <kbd>R</kbd> ,  <kbd>S</kbd> ) transform the origin.

You can also snap the origin to some vertex or between some vertices to position it and then with Affect Only Origins still enabled, create some custom transform orientation based on some element of your object in edit mode and Object -> Transform -> Align to Transform Orientation to align objects local space to the custom transform orientation like detailed in an answer to this question: [Setting an Object's Origin to match its Face Normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/192616/60759)