# How to link object data whilst keeping the location and rotation of all objects

Tags: modifiers, linked-data, instances, object-mode, curve-modifier

I have a pretty hefty frame structure that I need to optimise. This was created by arraying a single smaller section of the frame along a curve, then arraying the result 32 times around an empty. Therefore all of these items are identical. [image]

[image]

I have applied the arrays, separated by loose parts, and am now trying to make them all 'instances' of the selected frame in image 2. I'm doing this with CTRL + L -> Link Object data [image]

However, the other gurders just vanish
[image]

I have read one thread suggesting that by applying the location properties of the original I may have 'baked' the location of the object into it's 'Object Data', so I have attempted to fix this by selecting OBJECT -> CLEAR -> LOCATION (I have also done this for the scale and rotation just to see if it works)[image]

However this doesn't change the outcome. Another thread suggested that by setting each individual frames point of origin to centre mass that it would work. This resolves the issue of the location, but as you can see it still resets the orientation.
[image]

All together I'm stumped, but I'm guessing what I'm trying to do IS possible. Send help! Thankyou

Comment: It's not possible to do it purely automated. You need to do some manual adjustments to the origin of each object and then you can link the object data. I had the same problem and this was my solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79322/linking-object-data-without-changing-rotation/258824#258824

Comment: Yikes. I saw this answer yesterday but as ive got nearly 3,000 gurders i was hoping I wouldnt have to do it manually. Thankyou

Comment: it actually is impossible. because there is no way for blender to know how to orient the object. it can only base it on the orientation of the origin. that's why we need to orient each origin to tell blender that this is the orientation it needs to use when linking. can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com