# blender linking objects doesnt take rotation into account

Tags: instances

[image: example]

how can I make it so it actually takes the rotation of the linking into account.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide more details. Do you mean the object's actual rotation or the local rotation within the object?

Comment: You can rotate the object in Edit mode, the other mesh will rotate as well, but the origin won't be aligned with the faces anymore. Why don't you rotate the 3 objects with the Individual Origins option selected in the Transform Pivot Point panel? It seems like this is what you want to achieve, no?

Comment: Maybe related to this question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79322/linking-object-data-without-changing-rotation